# Unity - Spawning enemies on land

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new at Unity and I am stuck on one thing. I would like to ensure that the enemies spawn on the grass and not in the water and not on the colliders. I created the map using the Tiled program. Is there an effective solution? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to check tile on every layer, and if there is only grass tile, then can be spawned. But that was before i drew map in Tiled. I have map drew in Unity with TileMap.

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a strategy type game, you will need to store data about the map tiles in a 2D array like Map[x,y] so you can calculate things like movement, combat, resource gathering,victory points.

I have a TileType structure containing info on each tile based on your game rule requirements eg:

```
    struct TileType
{
    public int TerrainType;     // Terain type 1= grass 2= water 3 = city etc
    public int rot;             // Rotation of sprite to create variation (1-4,1=90 deg,2=180 deg etc
    public string Name;         // Description of tile type eg "Sports Store"
    public string SpriteName;   // string of sprite to use to display tile
    public bool SeeThrough;     // True if Tile allows LOS through it
}
```

I would set up the map as a 2D array of these tileType as follows:

```
private TileType[,] Map = new TileType[MapMaxX, MapMaxY];
```

You can then allow your game logic (ie where to spawn units) to check the proposed tile is legal as follows

```
if ((Map[x, y].TerrainType=1))  // Grass tile
      { return true; }
    else
    {
        return false;     // Non grass tile
    }
```

Comment: Oh I see, but how can i connect this structure with my tilemap? I have grid and single tilemap for grass, water, path etc. Or how can i fill it?

Comment: And it is not strategy game, it is top-down RPG, and i want my enemies spawn on grass, not in water and not on path, maybe i future not spawn in villages